# AngularJS toaster individual toast position

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toast, toastr

I have configured toasts globally in html

```
<toaster-container toaster-options="{'close-button': true, 'position-class': 'toast-bottom-right'}"></toaster-container>
```

and here is how i pop them

```
          core.toaster.pop({
              type: 'info',
              title: 'some title',
              timeout: 0
          });
```

I was wondering how I can position each toast individually and override global configuration from html. By default they are positioned bottom-right but for example I want one toast to be displayed top-right. Adding something like *positionClass: 'toast-top-right'* in toaster.pop doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

You can create another toaster container for your toaster, which You need to locate in different location by the use of toaster_id.

See this [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/1PP56s/) for working Model.

Hope, This one will be helpful...